# how to parse a double out of json using nlohmann json library

Tags: json, parsing

I'm using the nlohmann json library, and I cannot find examples anywhere of how to parse single elements out of parsed JSON...
{
        "objtype": "thingname",
        "id": "-5846147464469410021",
        "things": "[]"
}

I'd like to get the id out as a integer or a double if it was "3.4"

say p is a parsed json and I do a 
royaltyRate =std::stof(p["royaltyrate"]);
It won't cast properly?  How do I pull the sdt::string out to get the value?

Answer (score 1):

```
nlohmann::json json = {
  {"objtype", "thingname"}, 
  {"id",  "3.4" },
  {"things", "[]"} 
};

double id = std::stod(json["id"].get<nlohmann::json::string_t>());

std::cout << "id = " << id << std::endl;
```